Python Pandas division incorrect number
I perform a very simple calculation in pandas and yet the result is wrong:
vysledek["Market cap EBITDA multipl last 4 Q"] = vysledek["Market Capitalization"] / vysledek[ "EBITDA last 4 quarters"]

vysledek.loc[(vysledek.CP == "GRPN") & (vysledek.DATUM == "2024-06-20")][["CLOSE", "Share Issued", "Market Capitalization", "EBITDA last 4 quarters", "Market cap EBITDA multipl last 4 Q"]]




Market Capitalization
EBITDA last 4 quarters
Market cap EBITDA multipl last 4 Q




581665650.50
81000000.00
166.20



Market cap EBITDA multipl last 4 Q should be 7,1.
Data types of columns are floats.
I checked the data types. Also I tryied to investigate the Market Capitalization column as it was created by a pivot table and join to vysledek table.

I can't reproduce that. I get 7.181057.

I started with vysledek = pd.DataFrame({"Market Capitalization": [581665650.50], "EBITDA last 4 quarters": [81000000.00]})

Since 166.20 ≈ 581665650.50 / 3500000.00, I would guess that maybe you somehow changed the value of the "EBITDA last 4 quarters" column before you printed out that row.
Python dataframes are passed by reference, so any intermediate function that mutates the values within a dataframe that is passed in as an argument would also mutate the original dataframe itself.
If you paste your entire code snippet, we can help you debug further.
